# Business logic in java websocket endpoint/JAX-RS?

Tags: java, web-services, websocket, business-logic

What's the best practices for implementing business logic in a web-application that uses a Websocket connection? specifically, how to use a Java websocket endpoint effectively to implement services and functionalities of the system?
Does the websocket endpoint replace Java web-services (JAX-RS) functionality entirely?

Comment: Is this using Servlet 3.0 ServerEndpoint?

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is not a replacement for JAX-RS.

Both technologies have their usecases; if I were you, I would do my research before asking questions like this one.

The first question is about the business logic - and that always depends. You can adapt in some way MVC patter when dealing with JAX-RS, since there is a tight connection between Http Request and Response and you can even use some templating engine to process your output (Jersey - JAX-RS RI - contains pre-built support for this scenario). WebSocket is very different in terms of data processing, there is one "persistent" TCP connection which you can use to transmit messages from/to either side, which usually requires different programming model and typical usecase would include sending/receiving short status update messages to some interactive front-end (javascript) application.